# django didn't shows the pictures

Tags: python, django, django-admin

when i add posts in django admistration it did't show the photos(.jpg)
[image]

[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: Show us your `html` where you displays the picture

Comment: Did you add the media view urls? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/static-files/#serving-files-uploaded-by-a-user-during-development

Comment: also please provide the settings where you specify the `MEDIA_ROOT` parameter

Comment: i added MEDIA_ROOT settings